# EWS email exchange: getting message-id from a mail from Sent items

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm developping a tool that allow to handle and move emails in Exchange.
For moving the mails I do need the message-Id. My issue is that when I intercept mails stored in a folder, I also get sent emails. For those mail, i do not retrieve any Message-Id.

My issue is that i met the following case: one sent email was found in the inbox folder. Unfortunatelly, I do not get any message-Id when i get the information details. Is there a way to get this information from this mail ?

[image]

Comment: What API and language are you using?

Comment: I'm using EAGetMail. Language is C#. My issue is that i can't get emailId when a user moves a sent item in inbox folder.

Comment: So it is POP3 or IMAP4? You really need to work with the EAGetMail vendor.

Comment: i use IMAP4... the issue is that i can't even access to messageId in outlook...

Comment: You really need to contact whoever created EAGetMail.